# net Node.js Error: read ECONNRESET (on Windows)

Tags: node.js

I am attempting to use the net lib in Node.js to do simple message passing.  In the [example](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener) on Nodejs.org they provide the following code as a basic echo server:

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(c) { //'connection' listener
  console.log('server connected');
  c.on('end', function() {
    console.log('server disconnected');
  });
  c.write('hello\r\n');
  c.pipe(c);
});
server.listen(8124, function() { //'listening' listener
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

and a client for said server:

```
var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect({port: 8124},
    function() { //'connect' listener
  console.log('client connected');
  client.write('world!\r\n');
});
client.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
  client.end();
});
client.on('end', function() {
  console.log('client disconnected');
});
```

The example above works, however, if you remove the `client.end();` from the client code and force close the script on the client end (simulating a client crashing) the server crashes as well with the error:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:558:19)
```

I attempted to catch the error in the server code with `c.on("error",function(){})` as well as `server.on('error', function (e) {});` but in both cases the server still crashes when the client disconnects without using `client.end()`

What is the propper way of checking for this error so that the server does a `console.log('connection reset by peer')` instead of crashing?

UPDATE:
I tried this same code on my linux box and it seems to work just fine ... so why does it work in linux but not in windows?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `server.on('error')` handler?

Comment: @Joe Yes, as stated above I attempted to catch the error in the server code with `c.on("error",function(){})` as well as `server.on('error', function (e) {});` but in both cases the server still crashes when the client disconnects without using client.end()

Comment: Can you show your code with the error handlers included?  That should work.

Comment: @Joe Code and Error as requested: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7308460/images/NetError.PNG

Answer (score 2):

you can catch that error by adding this code inside yours 'createServer' function:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    console.log("Node NOT Exiting...");
});
```

Comment: This should be the answer. This works great for catching this error when it occurs (which seems to be occasionally).